# Code First EF call a stored procedure from a different database to later do insert data in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application where I am using Code first migrations and EF and I have my connection string in file App.config and all that goes with Code first migrations workflow and all is working fine. The issue I am having now and I am not able to find a solution anywhere online. So, what I need to know and hopefully is possible is to call a Stored Procedure from a different existing database because my existing program already have a connection string that connect to my main database but now I need to be able to somehow to connect to the other database and to call that stored procedure from that other database.

So, far I was able to find how to call a stored procedure but only found example where they call a stored procedure from the same database not other database.

So, please let me know how can I call a stored procedure from a different database still using code first workflow migration so I can add it to my dbsets. so, if is possible I would like if you can send me an code example how to do it would be great.

Comment: You can put more than one connection string into the config file. Just choose the one you need in code. Also, consider Dapper for calling the stored procedure. No need to do that by the context.

Comment: I see, I didn't know I could do that in the app.config file to add another connection string, but only concern of adding the second connection string is that other database that has the stored procedure is that is a huge database with thousands of tables,view and stored procedures, so can I add the second connection string and then just call the 1 stored procedure I need only that one? yes I was thinking of using the Dapper, but I would like to be consistent and since I am using code first migrations and dbContext I want to stick with that.

Comment: Of course you can. Whatever you'll use to call the stored procedure, it doesn't know anything of the rest of the database.

Comment: So, @GertArnold I added the second connectionstring please take a look and let me know if looks correct the dbMain is my main database and the db2 is the database where I will call the SP: `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BarcodeReceivingDbContext" connectionString="data source=server; initial catalog=dbMain; integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="BarcodeReceivingDatexDbContext" connectionString="data source=server; initial catalog=db2; integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: thanks man that resolved my issue by getting another connection string to the app.config file.